# Custom image sizes for custom field media uploads in WordPress

Tags: image, wordpress, custom-fields

When we simply want to show an image defined by a custom field (say "feature-image") we'd use:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'feature-image', true); ?>" />
```

And now lets consider that due to my media settings, two more sizes of the same image above are created -- 310x150 and 150x75 pixels each. How do I call them? (I mean, code for each image -- I want to call each image size separately.) Is there a code similar to above that could use?

***PS:** I've noticed that questions requiring some code are being asked here on SO, and not WP.SE (at least not always). So, I thought it would be better to ask mine here as well.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the image sizes you want, then you can use

```
wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $size, $icon, $attr );
```

You will of course have to find the attachment id to call  wp_get_attachment_image.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image

Answer (score -1):

its just  a hint..

try and check

```
print_r(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'feature-image')) //last param removed
```

Comment: You probably misunderstood my question -- I was asking for the PHP code to call each image (size) separately.